# adding t.reference or t.belongs_to for models in has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a has many through relationship. Should I have foreign key in Physician and patient model?

```
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :physicians do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.references :patient, index: true
  t.timestamps null: false
 end

 create_table :patients do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.references :physician, index: true
  t.timestamps null: false
 end

 create_table :appointments do |t|
  t.belongs_to :physician, index: true
  t.belongs_to :patient, index: true
  t.datetime :appointment_date
  t.timestamps null: false
 end
end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need need to add index in both physicians and patients table, since your appointments table holding both of these indexes. You can access Patients of a Physician, vice versa through this association itself, all you need to do is mention it in your physician and patient model,

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

and your migration file should be like this.

```
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :physicians do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :patients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :appointments do |t|
      t.belongs_to :physician, index: true
      t.belongs_to :patient, index: true
      t.datetime :appointment_date
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are adding references that will generate the foreign key in its corresponding table.